# SSL meteor Not Working.. Stuck in Spinner (loads nav bar and sidebar but nothing else)

Tags: ssl, nginx, meteor, meteor-up

I've been having an issue for days and I don't know how to fix it.

I am trying to setup my SSL certificate, and for some reason the site works on http, and then when I try to load https, it loads only the navbar and sidebar, and then it's stuck on the spinner.

When I examine at the network connections on chrome, it keeps trying to load xhr and websockets.

In safari I get this error in the console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite/sockjs/530/72iokiqa/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established
```

I am trying to set the headers, in particular the x-forwarded-proto header, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I am using mup.

```
// Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "https://inslim.com"
  },
  "ssl": {
    "pem": "./ssl.pem"
  }
```

For some reason, when I try to add a por to the env variable, it won't allow me to do mup deploy. It will break and the site will go down.

I am also confused with nginx. I installed it and I set it up, but I don't think it's making any difference. If I run 'service nginx stop' or service nginx start, it doesn't make any difference.

Can someone help me? Any advice or anything would help. Or if you need any other info please let me know.

Here's a screenshot of my spinner of death
[image]

Comment: Do you have the force-ssl package added to your application?

Comment: I had it at one point, but disabled it since https doesn't work.. so the redirect was just sending everyone to a broken site.. why?

Comment: I was just wondering because you did not mention it in your description and wanted to make sure that you tried to use that in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssl` part of your configuration JSON looks fine, but your `env` part needs a little modification. The `env` part of the configuration JSON should at least look something like this:

```
"env": {
    "PORT": 80, // Defaults to 80, but could be different if app is configured differently
    "ROOT_URL": "http://inslim.com"
}
```

If you do not have the `force-ssl` package already added to your application, I would suggest adding that (don't worry, it is a core Meteor package). If you do not also have the `spiderable` package added to your application, then your `ROOT_URL` element in your JSON can remain prefixed with `http`, but if you do have the `spiderable` package added to your application, you will need to change that `ROOT_URL` element prefix in your JSON to be `https`. All of this information is per the documentation for Meteor Up, which can be found [here](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#example-file). Also, I can confirm that this setup with the JSON works because I have a production application that is running with this exact setup without any issues.

Comment: I tried doing your suggestions but it still is not working. When you set it up did you use nginx or just meteor-up? Also, what platform did you use to host? I'm using digitalocean, which I'm sure it's ok but not sure if I missed something there. I think this whole thing has something to do with websockets but not sure how to fix.

Comment: Originally I tried performing the setup with NginX with no success. Since I was only trying to run the one app on my server, I realized that I didn't really have a need to complicate the process by including NginX in the process. Do you have a specific need for using NginX to setup this application? If not, I would highly suggest going the pure-Meteor-Up route and cutting the NginX complication out entirely. If you do have a specified need for NginX, there is [this guide](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/wiki/Using-Meteor-Up-with-NginX-vhosts) to doing so.